# x64 Linux reverse-engineering - understanding asm code (rootme like)

Tags: linux, 64-bit, reverse-engineering

In a rootme exercise, i'm trying to bypass the control impleted to protect a "read" function. You'll find enclosed the code i'm refering to. 
As you may understand, i can inject data (with limitations) in rax (with the limitation that *ax* be under *100h* due to the previous instruction:

```
cmp ax, 100h
```

I know I can change *eax* value before entering that part of the programe (part of the programe before the asm instructions enclosed). However, i have the feeling that the following instruction prevent from reading the *ah* part of the *eax* register.

```
movzx eax, word ptr [rax]
```

Would you have any idea if it would be possible to write into *ah* so that it be taken into account by the read function?

Thanks a lot! Sorry if all is not very clear, I can try to re-explain if needed.

disassembled piece of code [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2g5Q.png)

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking. Do you just want to write a value to `ah`? If so, then you should state which debugger you are using. If you want to chat about these things, then maybe [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to discuss it.

Comment: Yes, you can modify AH. How to do that depends on your debugger. Remember IDA is primarily an interactive disassembler - not a debugger. It has a default plugin debugger but most people use some other debugger.

Comment: Asked on the  Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange. Thanks for the hint jww!